# Header redirect not working and user check not updating sql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a redirect in my PHP file which checks user data when they log in.

I believe, the problem may be in the login_check if statement section. I have checked the other sections, and:

- The include db.php data is correct.
- The username/password if statement returns the echo when I don't fill in one of the fields.
- The "user info validates the db" seems correct, the table is called "users"
- The else statement at the end also returns if intentionally type in a wrong password.
- I have googled and triple checked the header redirect statement and am sure it's the correct syntax (I've played around)

**I notice** that column "last_login" does not get updated with now() value. This is why I think the problem is in this area, but I can't figure it out.

PHP version: **5.6.30**

Here is the php file:

```
<?
    /* Check User Script */
    session_start();  // Start Session

    include 'db.php';
    // Conver to simple variables
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if((!$username) || (!$password)){
        echo "Please enter ALL of the information! <br />";
        include 'login_form.html';
        exit();
    }

    // Convert password to md5 hash
    $password = md5($password);

    // check if the user info validates the db
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' AND activated='1'");
    $login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($login_check > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        foreach( $row AS $key => $val ){
            $$key = stripslashes( $val );
        }
            // Register some session variables!
            session_register('first_name');
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
            session_register('last_name');
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
            session_register('email_address');
            $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;
            session_register('special_user');
            $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;

            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_login=now() WHERE userid='$userid'");

            header("Location: login_success.php");
        }
    } 

    else {
        echo "You could not be logged in! Either the username and password do not match or you have not validated your membership!<br />
        Please try again!<br />";
        include 'login_form.html';
    }
    ?>
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Try running your SQL query with the same login and password you've tried to login with, and see if any result is produced.

Comment: First thing you need to stop using `mysql` it has been deprecated switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` and learn how to use prepared statements your code is wide open to be hacked using SQL injection.

Comment: The mysql PHP extension is dead -- Stop using the mysql PHP extension. It is old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.0. Use mysqli or PDO_mysql instead. And don't mix them

Comment: @bharatparmar why? now() is perfectly fine for this purpose, assuming last_login is a date field. Why write a more complicated PHP code to do what MySQL already does natively? I think that's not the root of the problem.

Comment: @Mike why such an ancient version of PHP? It was end-of-life in 2008! http://php.net/manual/php4.php

Comment: P.S. If I had to guess your problem I'd say probably userid is an int field in the DB? And you're passing the value of it in as a string, so they can't match each other. But parameterising properly using a modern version of PHP and a supported DB library would have solved that for you in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
@ADyson, I double checked this with my hosting provider and they confirm I actually have 5.6.30, sorry about that. It did say in phpMyAdmin that it was 4.*.* but it isn't.

Comment: @ADyson, yes userid is an int field on auto increment.

Comment: @Sand, really? I didn't realise that mySQL was so unsafe. Then in that case I will look into mySQLi or PDO, choose and set up the connection again.
Thanks for the feedback everyone

Comment: "It did say in phpMyAdmin that it was 4.*.*". Are you sure that wasn't the version of the phpMyAdmin app? Anyway yes the `mysql_` PHP library has been deprecated for years now, partly due to security issues, including its inability to provide proper protection against SQL injection attacks, and removed entirely in PHP7. So if you carry on using it, your code will eventually stop working entirely when you come to upgrade. http://bobby-tables.com/ has a good (and humorous) explanation of why your current code is risky, and how to fix it using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @ADyson, correct, it was the version of the phpMyAdmin app, my mistake. Thanks a lot for the detail and the URL, I'll have a read (/giggle) through and re-write my files.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of changing your code to show you how it's done in `PDO` and there is a change in you `UPDATE` statement as well.

**NOTE:** [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) to the list of supported timezones

```
<?
    /* Check User Script */
    session_start();  // Start Session

    include 'db.php';
    // Conver to simple variables
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //Set time
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Adak");//Set the correct time zone
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    if((!$username) || (!$password)){
        echo "Please enter ALL of the information! <br />";
        include 'login_form.html';
        exit();
    }

    // Convert password to md5 hash
    $password = md5($password);

    // check if the user info validates the db
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password= :password AND activated='1'");
    $login_check = $dbConnect -> prepare($sql);
    $login_check -> bindParam(':username',$username);
    $login_check -> bindParam(':password',$password);
    $login_check -> execute();

    $rowCount = $login_check -> rowCount();

    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $login_check -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        foreach( $row AS $key => $val ){
            $$key = stripslashes( $val );
        }
            // Register some session variables!
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;            
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
            $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;
            $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;

            $upstmt=("UPDATE users SET last_login=:now WHERE userid= :userid");
            $query = $dbConnect -> prepare($upstmet);
            $query -> bindPara(':userid', $userid);
            $query -> bindPara(':now', $now);
            $query -> execute();

            header("Location: login_success.php");
        }
    } 

    else {
        echo "You could not be logged in! Either the username and password do not match or you have not validated your membership!<br />
        Please try again!<br />";
        include 'login_form.html';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: this is going to produce a syntax error due to the use of " " in the date() call. You also only updated one of the queries using PDO. The other one is still using mysql_. And the while loop won't work because it relies on mysql_ still.

Comment: ok that's better. But why does "now()" need to be changed for a "date()" call? Unless last_login is a string field, but even then it should just dump a string version of the date into the field. But we don't know that. Also the code will try to use the MySQL Date function, not the PHP one, and it's an invalid usage, since that doesn't accept any parameters, and also produces an output without the time component. I think, if you use it, it needs to be outside the quotes and concatenated with `.`.

Comment: Yes you're right I didn't think it through will change that thx.

Comment: it should be `now()` instead of just `now`. I could be wrong but I don't think you can call MySQL functions without the parentheses. I suspect it will try and interpret it as a column name.

Comment: I defined it out side the while `$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` at the top of the code with the time zone.

Comment: oh sorry yes you did. Didn't see the `:`. Still don't understand why you can't use MySQL `now()` though. Why write some more complicated PHP to do what MySQL already does natively?

Answer (score 0):

Quick update, when I remove the 4 session_register(); lines:

```
// Register some session variables!
            **session_register('first_name');**
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
            **session_register('last_name');**
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
            **session_register('email_address');**
            $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;
            **session_register('special_user');**
            $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
```

The checkuser.php (name of this file) script ran and then redirected me onto the login_success.php page. It was the session_register(''); causing it because of depreciation. After running, it updated what it needed to update in the table 'users' as well (the last_login data).

Still, I should go over my files and update to mySQLi